# GWTP HttpSessions with Cookies disabled

Tags: gwt, cookies, httpsession, gwtp

I have a GWT app that is loaded within an iFrame. The app uses GWTP for client server communication. In the ActionHandler implementation a HttpSession Provider is injected.

```
@Inject
private final Provider<HttpSession> sessionProvider;
```

If cookies are disabled in the browser, a **new** HttpSession is provided each time the provider calls .get()

```
requestProvider.get();
```

So, there is no chance to store any information in the http session.

How can this problem be solved?

Is there a way to add the jsessionid to each action request and if so, how do I get the jsessionid?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the approach that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518306/session-tracking-using-httpsession-object-if-cookies-is-disabled-at-browser). The technique relies on url rewrite for sessionid.

You can also reference section **"Using URL Rewriting Instead of Cookies"** from oracle documentation [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/sessions.html)